# Ackermann Function

Tags: macros, errors, recursion, robust-commands

I am trying to write a macro to evaluate the result of the Ackermann function.
If anyone doesn't know it, is defined as follows:

[image]

So I am trying to write a code that is able to compute it but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Of course, the whole point of the Ackermann function is that its values get extremely large for moderate m and n. So this will be an exercise in frustration, I'm afraid.

Comment: A(4, 2) is about 2×10¹⁹⁷²⁸

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a `\romannumeral`-expansion-based solution using the [bigintcalc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc)-package.

Be aware: The Ackermann-function being defined recursively implies nesting calls to `\romannumeral` which takes its toll on the semantic nest.

The solutions of egreg, wipet and Marcel Krüger don't have this problem.

To be honest: I think TeX is not the right tool for calculating values of the Ackermann-function. Probably an approach is better where `\write18` is used for calling an external program which does the calculations more efficiently and which stores the results in a text-file which afterwards can be processed by TeX via `\input` for importing the results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}

\newcommand\UDfirstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UDsecondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UDPassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\UDstopromannumeral{\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00}%

% \Ackermann{m}{n}

\newcommand\Ackermann{%
  \romannumeral\Ackermannloop
}%

\newcommand\Ackermannloop[2]{%
  \ifnum\bigintcalcCmp{#1}{0}=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UDstopromannumeral\bigintcalcInc{#2}}{%
    \ifnum\bigintcalcCmp{#2}{0}=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
    {%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Ackermannloop\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\bigintcalcDec{#1}}{1}%
    }%
    {%
       \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
         \romannumeral
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\bigintcalcDec{#2}}{\Ackermannloop{#1}}}{%
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Ackermannloop\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\bigintcalcDec{#1}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

$\text{Ackermann}(0, 0)=\Ackermann{0}{0}$

$\text{Ackermann}(1, 0)=\Ackermann{1}{0}$

$\text{Ackermann}(2, 0)=\Ackermann{2}{0}$

$\text{Ackermann}(0, 1)=\Ackermann{0}{1}$

$\text{Ackermann}(0, 2)=\Ackermann{0}{2}$

$\text{Ackermann}(1, 1)=\Ackermann{1}{1}$

$\text{Ackermann}(2, 2)=\Ackermann{2}{2}$

$\text{Ackermann}(2, 3)=\Ackermann{2}{3}$

$\text{Ackermann}(3, 3)=\Ackermann{3}{3}$

$\text{Ackermann}(3, 4)=\Ackermann{3}{4}$

% \Ackermann{4}{2}
% I suppose the above yields something like:
% ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Here is a solution using classical TeX tools (without expl3).

```
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\Ac#1#2{\ifnum#1=0 \afterfi{\the\numexpr#2+1\relax}%
            \else \afterfi{\ifnum#2=0 \afterfi{\Aeval{#1-1}{1}}%
                           \else \afterfi{\Aeval{#1-1}{\Aeval{#1}{#2-1}}}\fi}\fi}
\def\Aeval#1#2{\expanded{\noexpand\Ac{\the\numexpr#1}{\the\numexpr#2}}}
\def\A(#1,#2){$A(#1,#2)=\Ac{#1}{#2}$\par}

\A(0,0)
\A(1,0)
\A(2,0)
\A(0,1)
\A(0,2)
\A(1,1)
\A(2,2)
\A(2,3)
\A(3,3)
\A(3,4)

\bye
```

The `\afterfi` macro is used in order to spare TeX stack.

Comment: +1 I like your use of `\expanded` using classical TeX tools. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Of course this needs a LuaTeX answer. I optimized some of the easy cases, but it is based on 64bit signed integers, so it fails whenever any value gets bigger than `2^63-1=9223372036854775807`. It does check for this though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
  local maxint = math.maxinteger
  local almostmaxint = math.maxinteger
  local almosthalfmaxinteger = maxint/2-2
  local function A(m, n)
    if m == 0 then
      if n==maxint then
        error[[Overflow]]
      end
      return n+1 end
    if n == 0 then return A(m-1, 1) end
    if m == 1 then
      if n==almostmaxint or n ==maxint then
        error[[Overflow]]
      end
      return n+2
    end % Optimize simple case
    if m == 2 then
      if n > almosthalfmaxinteger then
        error[[Overflow]]
      end
      return 2*n+3
    end % Optimize simple case
    return A(m-1, A(m, n-1))
  end
  ackermann = A
}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\ackermann{mm}{\directlua{tex.write(ackermann(token.scan_int(), token.scan_int()))} \numexpr#1\relax \numexpr#2\relax}

\begin{document}

$A(0,0)=\ackermann{0}{0}$

$A(1,0)=\ackermann{1}{0}$

$A(2,0)=\ackermann{2}{0}$

$A(0,1)=\ackermann{0}{1}$

$A(0,2)=\ackermann{0}{2}$

$A(1,1)=\ackermann{1}{1}$

$A(2,2)=\ackermann{2}{2}$

$A(2,3)=\ackermann{2}{3}$

$A(3,3)=\ackermann{3}{3}$

$A(3,7)=\ackermann{3}{7}$

$A(3,8)=\ackermann{3}{8}$

$A(3,9)=\ackermann{3}{9}$

$A(3,20)=\ackermann{3}{20}$

$A(3,40)=\ackermann{3}{40}$

$A(4,0)=\ackermann{4}{0}$

$A(4,1)=\ackermann{4}{1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course Lua is better at arithmetic than TeX! :-)

Answer (score 11):

It's very simple: just implement the recursive definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ackermann}{mm}
 {
  \needle_ackermann:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \needle_ackermann:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 0 }
   {% m = 0
    \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 }
   }
   {% m > 0
    \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
     {% n = 0
      \needle_ackermann:ee { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } } { 1 }
     }
     {% n > 0
      \needle_ackermann:ee
       { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } }
       { \int_eval:n { \needle_ackermann:ee { #1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } } } }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \needle_ackermann:nn { ee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$A(0,0)=\ackermann{0}{0}$

$A(1,0)=\ackermann{1}{0}$

$A(2,0)=\ackermann{2}{0}$

$A(0,1)=\ackermann{0}{1}$

$A(0,2)=\ackermann{0}{2}$

$A(1,1)=\ackermann{1}{1}$

$A(2,2)=\ackermann{2}{2}$

$A(2,3)=\ackermann{2}{3}$

$A(3,3)=\ackermann{3}{3}$

$A(3,4)=\ackermann{3}{4}$

%%%%$A(3,8)=\ackermann{3}{8}$ %%% don't try this

%%%%$A(4,1)=\ackermann{4}{1}$ %%% don't try this

\end{document}
```

[image]

Memory gets exhausted whenever we try *n* = 8 or *m* = 4.

Comment: Nice way to kill your computer ;-) (Trying to calculate A(4,3) in `python`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHvd8.png)

Comment: @Rmano TeX fails more graciously. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

It's sad to be late at the party, but since a Lua(La)TeX answer has been already posted, I'll write a ConTeXt one (it can be easily adapted to LuaLaTeX using scanners as in the other LuaTeX answer, tho). Unless you want to freeze your computer, don't try to directly implement it, but rather slicing in simpler cases as other answers did. It won't crash and it'll print a warning instead. :)

Just to cheat a bit, we need the [`lua-nums`](https://github.com/user-none/lua-nums) library, available via Luarocks for the interested.

```
\startluacode
--Use bn if bn.lua is in your working directory:
--local bn = require"bn"
--Use nums.bn if you've installed it via Luarocks
local bn = require"nums.bn"

local function ackermann(m,n)
    local m, n = bn(m), bn(n)
    if m == bn(0) then return n + 1 end
    if m == bn(1) then return n + 2 end
    if m == bn(2) then return (n<<1) + 3 end
    if m == bn(3) then return (bn(1)<<(n+3)) - 3 end
    if m == bn(4) and n == bn(0) then return 13 end
    if m == bn(4) and n == bn(2) then return ((bn(1)<<65536) - 3) end
    if (m == bn(4) and n == bn(1)) or (m == bn(5) and n == bn(0)) then return 65533 end
    context.writestatus("ackermann","Please don't!") 
    return "" 
end

--\hyphenateddigits requires an up-to-date ConTeXt
interfaces.implement{
    name            = "ackermann",
    public          = true,
    arguments   = "2 strings",
    actions         = 
    function(x,y)
        context.hyphenateddigits(tostring(ackermann(x,y)))
    end
}
\stopluacode
\starttext
\startTEXpage
%% Examples
%% Rather boring
\startlines
\ackermann{0}{0}
\ackermann{1}{0}
\ackermann{1}{1}
\ackermann{2}{0}
\ackermann{2}{1}
\ackermann{2}{2}
\ackermann{3}{0}
\ackermann{3}{1}
\ackermann{3}{2}
\ackermann{3}{3}
\ackermann{3}{70}
\ackermann{4}{0}
\ackermann{4}{1}
\stoplines
\stopTEXpage
%% Fun
\ackermann{4}{2}
\stoptext
```

[image]

For `\ackermann{4}{2}` we have something quite interesting:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I add another approach based on "using table".

```
\useOpTeX
\def\Ac#1#2{\ifcase#1
   \the\numexpr #2+1\relax \or
   \the\numexpr #2+2\relax \or
   \the\numexpr 2*#2+3\relax \or
   \ifnum#2<28 \the\numexpr 2\fornum 1..#2+2\do{*2}-3\relax \else \toobig{#1}{#2}\fi \or
   \ifcase#2 13\or 65533\else \toobig{#1}{#2}\fi \or
   \ifnum#2=0 65533\else \toobig{#1}{#2}\fi \else
   \toobig{#1}{#2}\fi
}
\def\toobig#1#2{A(#1,#2)}
\def\A(#1,#2){$A(#1,#2)=\Ac{#1}{#2}$\par}

\A(0,0)
\A(1,0)
\A(2,0)
\A(0,1)
\A(0,2)
\A(1,1)
\A(2,2)
\A(2,3)
\A(3,3)
\A(3,20)
\A(5,0)

\bye
```

The table row for m=3 is calculated as 2^{n+3}-3 and I used the expandable `\fornum` from OpTeX here. If you are not using OpTeX then you can use another `\ifcase` here.

The calculation never crashes. Maximal calculated number is 2^30-3.

Answer (score 7):

A little late but here's a `sagetex` solution. This package gives you access to a computer algebra system, SAGE, which includes Python. Python is a popular language so it's easy to find code for it on the internet and get on with your work. Prune's answer at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592768/it-is-possible-to-compute-recursive-ackermannm-n-function-with-args-m-4-and-n) is copied and pasted into LaTeX code at [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) to give

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)
memo = {}

def ack(m, n):
    if not (m, n) in memo:
        result = (n + 1) if m == 0 else (
            ack(m-1, 1) if n == 0 else ack(m-1, ack(m, n-1)))
        memo[(m, n)] = result
    return memo[(m, n)]
\end{sagesilent}
\noindent $A(0,0)=\sage{ack(0,0)}$\\
$A(1,0)=\sage{ack(1,0)}$\\
$A(2,0)=\sage{ack(2,0)}$\\
$A(0,1)=\sage{ack(0,1)}$\\
$A(0,2)=\sage{ack(0,2)}$\\
$A(1,1)=\sage{ack(1,1)}$\\
$A(2,2)=\sage{ack(2,2)}$\\
$A(2,3)=\sage{ack(2,3)}$\\
$A(3,3)=\sage{ack(3,3)}$\\
$A(4,1)= \sage{ack(4,1)}$
\end{document}
```

The result running in Cocalc is:
[image]

SAGE is not part of LaTeX. Accessing it through a free Cocalc account is easier than downloading it to your computer.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another LuaLaTeX-based solution. It is quite minimalist in that it implements the function's definition directly -- without low-level optimizations and without guarding against overflows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\directlua{
```

```lua
function ackermann ( m , n )
   if       m==0 then return n+1
     elseif n==0 then return ackermann ( m-1 , 1 )
     else   return ackermann ( m-1 , ackermann ( m , n-1 ) )
   end
end
```

```latex
}
%% define a LaTeX utility macro to access the Lua function:
\newcommand\Ack[2]{\directlua{ tex.sprint ( ackermann ( #1 , #2 ) ) }}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A(0,0)  &= \Ack{0}{0} \\
A(4,0)  &= \Ack{4}{0} \\
A(3,7)  &= \Ack{3}{7} \\
A(3,9)  &= \Ack{3}{9} \\
A(3,11) &= \Ack{3}{11}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```